# How to put floating image (wrapped around text) aligned to the right with a centered caption in RMarkdown?

Tags: html, image, alignment, markdown, r-markdown

So far this gives me the result I want.

```
<img align="right" src="images/cobre.png">
```

But I'd like to put a centered caption below the image. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML output can be styled via CSS. The styles can either be included directly in the text, or put into a separate CSS stylesheet.

Here is how to use inline CSS:

````
```{=html}
<style type="text/css">
  .figure {
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
```

``` {r fig.cap = "Insert caption here", echo=FALSE}
knitr::include_graphics("images/cobre.png")
```
````

The advantage of using `knitr::include_graphics` over raw HTML is that `include_graphics` will also work for other output formats like word and pdf (although the figure won't be right aligned for these formats).